# How to get values from array created by toArray

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, laravel-5, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable to organize some slides.  I am able to return an array of the id's in their new order but am struggling with how to iterate over these in the controller to update the sort order of the slides.

The array looks like this

```
[2016-06-25 02:09:53] local.INFO: array (
'order' => 
array (
0 => '2',
1 => '3',
2 => '1',
3 => '4',
4 => '5',
5 => '6',
6 => '7',
7 => '8',
8 => '9',
9 => '10',
10 => '11',
11 => '12',
12 => '13',
13 => '14',
14 => '15',
15 => '16',
16 => '17',
17 => '18',
18 => '19',
19 => '20',
20 => '21',
21 => '22',
 ),
)
```

So the id's of the slides are being returned in the new order, which is what I need, but now I need to do a foreach loop, or something, with that id number and update the sort order.  Any help with how to grab each value in a foreach loop (or whatever the best way to achieve this may be) would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to custom sort this array in controller?

Comment: I basically want to do a foreach loop, grab the slide that matches the id and then update that slides sort order with it's position (key + 1) in the array.  So in the array above the first slide, which is id of 2, would move to position 1 in the sort order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well in this case you will need a seperate array to store your result.

```
$new_sorted_array = [];
foreach($sorted_array as $key => $value)
{
 $new_sorted_array[$key + 1] = $value;
}
```

Or you can use only one array too.

```
$length = count($sorted_array);
for($i=$length ; $i >= 0 ; $i--)
{
 if($i == 0)
 {
   $sorted_array[$i] = 0; //some value if needed to specify.
 }
 $sorted_array[$i] = $sorted_array[i-1];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I am going to pick this up again tomorrow so I'll see if I can get this to work.

Comment: No problem at all. :)

Comment: Always here to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

`var points = [40, 100, 1, 5, 25, 10];
points.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});`

`1,5,10,25,40,100` will be the result of the code above

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp is a great source for sorting arrays

**EDIT:** Didn't notice the Laravel part. There is a method in Laravel called sort and another called sort recursive. Laravel has some good sample code regarding this. laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-sort

Comment: That is in javascript though right?  I need to do this in the Laravel controller, I am not sure how to apply this.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I thought you meant Javascript. I'm sorry about that. Try this. There is a method in laravel called sort and another called sort recursive. Laravel has some good sample code regarding this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-array-sort